# Image effect in website

Tags: javascript, css, image-manipulation

Please can anyone tell me the coding in terms of Js, css for displaying image effect like one in http://dalailama.com/ ie changing of images one after another. If possible let me know about adding video link in the sidebar with the minor screen.

Comment: @Dorji, If the answer works you need to accept it.

Comment: "i am new to stackoverflow" you've been a member for 48 days, i've been a member for 16. There are plenty of [FAQS](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Not trying to be harsh, but the better the question the better the answer.

Comment: @Alex..Oh..anyway my programming skills is so low that i am enforced to discuss the solution though i had done some research. I see sorry about my phrase" I am new to Stackoverflow"..Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<div id="testers">
  <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://regmedia.co.uk/2008/03/18/google_adwords_machine.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="morework">
  <div class="holderdiv">
    <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://www.swwebs.co.uk/images/google-pagerank.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="holderdiv">
    <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://regmedia.co.uk/2008/03/18/google_adwords_machine.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#morework{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function runIt(){
     $('#morework').find('.holderdiv').each(function(i, elem) {
       $("#testers").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
         $(this).html($(elem).html());
       }).fadeIn(1000, runIt);
     });
   };
   runIt()
 });
```

Check it out in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/sfsPx/

Comment: @Alex..i dont know whether i have done correct or not because i had saved js code in image.js and html code in my sidebar.php file and css code. but  the effect is not coming in my website. what i have to do?

Comment: Have you include jquery? Go to jquery.com and get the latest jquery js file. I'm not at my Pc so I can't supply the link.

Comment: @Alex...i have surfed jquery.com and i have pressed the download button but the code is so massive and i am totally confused.

Comment: Google also host the jquery lib, just add this to your HTML file `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: So did this work @Dorji? If so click the tick under the Vote up/down links. Also please go back over some of you previous questions and do the same if they have been successfully answered.