# Background-Image fade jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a div and I want to fade in and out of 5 different background images at random.

I have downloaded a jquery plugin for this, but unfortunately it alternates - I'll explain.

You must set a default background image (for this case lets say "image1") and then load an array of images (say image2, image3, image4, and image5). What the plugin does is duplicate the div and place it directly over the original one, then fades in and then out one of the array of images. The undesirable effect that I'm getting from this is:

1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5

as opposed to:

1,2,3,4,5

Because the fade out simple reveals the default image once again.

Without re-inventing the wheel is there a way to modify the code to that when the fade-in animation is complete (the default is completely concealed) I swap out the image on the background div so that when the fade out begins there's a new image below? I'm relatively new to JQuery and so this is not my strength.

Heres the action part of the plugin:

```
var tempImage = new Image();

jQuery(tempImage).load( function(){
    var newImage = ( helperElement.css('display') == 'block' ) ? jQuery(this) : jQuery(helperElement);
    newImage.css('backgroundImage', 'url('+tempImage.src+')');
    helperElement.animate( settings.effect, settings.duration, settings.easing, settings.callback );
});

tempImage.src = src;
```

And in my HTML:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('content_container_home').style.backgroundImage = "url('img/buttons.jpg')";
    $( function(){
        var bgImages = [ 'barker.jpg', 'boards.jpg', 'feet.jpg', 'glasses.jpg' ];
        var currImage = 'buttons.jpg';
        setInterval( function(){
            do{
                var randImage = bgImages[Math.ceil(Math.random()*(bgImages.length-1))];
            }while( randImage == currImage )
                currImage = randImage;
             $('#content_container_home').BgImageTransition( 'img/'+currImage );
            }, 5000)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117349/image-effect-in-website/5117436#5117436)

This should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<div id="testers">
  <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://regmedia.co.uk/2008/03/18/google_adwords_machine.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="morework">
  <div class="holderdiv">
    <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://www.swwebs.co.uk/images/google-pagerank.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="holderdiv">
    <div class="tester">
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.gif" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#morework{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function runIt(){
     $('#morework').find('.holderdiv').each(function(i, elem) {
       $("#testers").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
         $(this).html($(elem).html());
       }).fadeIn(1000, runIt);
     });
   };
   runIt()
 });
```

Check it out in action here - [http://jsfiddle.net/sfsPx/](http://jsfiddle.net/sfsPx/5/)

Comment: thing is, it needs to be on the background-image and not an actual img tag because I've applied properties such as background-size in the CSS which I need to affect the divs. http://jsfiddle.net/sfsPx/7/

Comment: ahhhh right, must have missed that bit. this answer is pretty useless then.